# How to upload a file from django view using filepath

Tags: django, django-models

I have to upload a file from django views using the file path from the local system. I'm using models.create method to save the filepath. But the image is not getting uploaded into the media directory.

I have tried the Content and File from django core.utils but it deos not work

```
def createevent(request):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.FILES_DIR) # Getting the directory with files
    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(file_path):
        f.extend(filenames)
        break
    f.remove(".DS_Store")
    img = random.choice(f) # Select a random file 
    pa = os.path.abspath(img) # absolute file path
    # pa = (img,File(pa))

    response = File(pa)
    print(pa)
    loc = "School Ground"
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        get_dateof = request.POST.get('dateof')
        get_nameof = request.POST.get('nameof')
        get_descof = request.POST.get('descof')
        new_report = Event.objects.create(
            name=get_nameof,
            description=get_descof,
            location=loc,
            timeoftheevent=get_dateof,
            user=request.user,
            image= pa 
            ) #creating a db record
    return HttpResponse('')
```

my models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    timeoftheevent = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image   = models.FileField(blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Can you show me your models.py

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA Added the models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
#This would return a path for your saved images using path name/filename you can always tweak this
def user_directory_path(instance,filename):
    return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.name, filename)

class Event(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    timeoftheevent = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image   = models.FileField(upload_to = user_directory_path, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

then in your views.py and I'm assuming myfile is the name of the file field in your html form

```
if request.method == 'POST' and and request.FILES['myfile']: 
        get_dateof = request.POST.get('dateof')
        get_nameof = request.POST.get('nameof')
        get_descof = request.POST.get('descof')
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']

        #creating a db record............
    return HttpResponse('')
```

you can have a look at [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html) if it helps